# laravel advanced join on 5 tables, with 2 tables campared

Tags: mysql, join, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm not even sure this is possible, I can get it to work up to the 2nd join function, then it just return null.

```
$articles = DB::table('courses')
     ->join('version','courses.current_version_id','=','version.id')
     ->join('category as c1', function($join1){
           $join1->on('courses.code','=','c1.title');
     })
     ->join('category as c2', function($join2){
           $join2->on('version.version_number','=','c2.title');
     })
     ->join('articleCategories','c2.id','=','articleCategories.cat_id')
     ->join('articles','articleCategories.article_id','=','articles.id')
     ->where('c2.parent_id','=','c1.id')
     ->where('courses.id','=',$course)
     ->select('courses.code','courses.title','version.version_number','articles.*')
     ->get();
```

Is this even possible? What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I've gotten it to return empty arrays by cleaning up some mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$fieldsToSelect = array(
    'courses.code',
    'courses.title',
    'courses.current_version_id',
    'version.version_number',
    'version.id',
    'category.id',
    'category.title',
    'articleCategories.cat_id',
    'articleCategories.article_id',
    'articles.*'
);

$articles = DB::table('courses')->join('version', function($join){
    $join->on('courses.current_version_id', '=', 'version.id');
})->join('category', function($join) {
    $join->on('courses.code', '=', 'category.title')
         ->on('version.version_number', '=', 'category.title');
})->join('articleCategories', function($join){
    $join->on('category.id', '=', 'articleCategories.cat_id');
})->join('articles', function($join){
    $join->on('articleCategories.article_id', '=', 'articles.id');
})
->get($fieldsToSelect);
```

Comment: One thing i see missing is the category.parent_id, this is important because it is likely there are similar named sub categories. like classXYZ > 1.0, classSTU>1.0. Each class has it's own category and each version is a sub category.

Comment: Then use an alias like `category as cat1`.

Comment: Could you please adjust your code to demonstrate this. I only ask because That's what I did in the question above, but it didn't work.

Comment: Use `select('version.id as ver1id', 'category.id as cat1Id')` and remove the `fieldsToSelect` from `get`, instead add all inside `select`. Just like you did an your question, make selections in `select` and call `get()` without any args. When selecting, use alias for duplicate fields, lioke `select(''courses.title' as ctitle', ''category.title' as catTitle')`.